# Regex in C# that contains "this" but not "that

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I need to filter a list of files.  Some of these are csv files, and of those, some of them are appended with a control tag, ".cntl".

Example: file1.csv, file1.csv.cntl

I would like to set up a regex that checks to see if a file contains "csv" and NOT "cntl".  Right now I've got this.

```
csv(?!cntl)
```

This is not working.  What would a proper regex be?

PS. This is all done in C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regex should check to see if a file ends with `.csv`

```
\.csv$
```

Remember that `csv` could be contained elsewhere in the file name.

Comment: Lot of varied answers, but this is incredibly simple.  Thank you.

Comment: @Norla, I'd have to argue that checking `string.EndsWith()` is far more simple than using a regex in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

The following is the pattern you want.

```
@"csv(?!\.cntl)"
```

But, wouldn't it be easier to check:

```
if (string.EndsWith("cntl"))
```

Using a regex is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I don't think that `@"csv!(?\.cntl)"` is a valid regex.

Comment: @eldare, I was having that same feeling, but I couldn't decide what I thought was wrong with it.  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @jjnguy: Negative lookahead should be `(?!<expr>)`. If you move the `!` it ought to be fine (and a quick test seems confirm that).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
csv(?!.*cntl)
```

Comment: If you have not  "." will it be possible to have a file that is not a "csv" real file.
"Myfilecsv" will to go to true

Comment: @sv88erik: Yes, but that's not the question the OP asked.

Comment: "Example: file1.csv, file1.csv.cntl" : as shown in this syntax
 :)

Comment: *"I would like to set up a regex that checks to see if a file contains 'csv' and NOT 'cntl'."*

Comment: And I reckon that this is the fault of the OP, then eksplene and file validation of file extensions. But of course you have a point that it has two different answers if you choose to interpret it as you do