# Find a pattern to match 'a', ignoring that 'a' which lies within 'b' and 'c'

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

**Need a compound expression for**

```
" from" such that " from" is not within parenthesis
```

(ignoring those which are in parenthesis) here `a=" from"; b="("; and c=")";`

**The closest (but invalid) pattern I could write is**

```
string pat = @"^((?!\(.* from.*\)).)* from((?!\(.* from.*\)).)*$";
```

my expression denies if any " from" is present in parenthesis but i want to strictly ignore such " from"

**Matches should be found in:**

```
1: " from" 2:select field1 from t1 (select field1 from t1)   ---- 1 time in both
3: select field1 from t1 (select field1 from t1)select field1 from t1  ---2 times
```

**Strings not containing matches:(Because i want to ignore the " from" within parenthesis)**

```
1: select field1 no_f_rom_OutOf_Parenthesis t1 (select field1 from t1)
2: (select field1 from t1)  3: "" (Empty String) 4. No word as form
0 times in all four strings
```

**Relevant Material:** (not much necessary to read)

The most helpful link nearer to my question telling how to match 'pattern' but not 'regular' has been a reply by stanav at Jul 31st, 2009, 08:05 AM in following link...

http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-578417.html

Also: [Regex in C# that contains "this" but not "that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402811/regex-in-c-sharp-that-contains-this-but-not-that)

Also: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

I have studied/searched about a week but still Its complex for me:)

Comment: Can the parentheses be nested?

Comment: Yes even they can be nested. But I have to find only that " from" which is not in any parenthesis. If it is found. Expression is matched

Comment: For SQL, you need a parser. For "hello bro! Whats up" you might be able to use regex.

Comment: I don't know if .NET's regexes can handle nested patterns, Perl's can be “recursive” AFAIK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman. Yes expressions are varibale

Comment: give more examples of valid and invalid output.. everything that u wrote may make sense to u but not others..so NEED more examples!

Comment: @Anirudha bro. I have made it shorter but tried to elaborate with examples as you told. Is it making some sense now?

Comment: @SamiAkram if i got u right,u want queries which are not in parenthesis..right!If that's so check out the answer!

Comment: @Anirudha
I can have a string 'bb hj exp ab'  and 'hh exp bb hj exp ab' if I say ignore any exp surrounded by 'bb.*exp.*ab' and match others, I would get matched only first 'exp' of string2.
Here " from" = "exp" and parenthesis '(',')' = 'bb','ab'

if I get the solution 'a' ignoring 'a' in 'b'. It will be some combination of any two expressions and dynamically work for new situations

Comment: it would be too complicated..try to get out of `Regex` and think what would you do if there were no `regex`..try to break the code into parts.it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, even with arbitrarily nested parentheses:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"\sfrom           # Match ' from'
    (?=                # only if the following regex can be matched here:
     (?:               # The following group, consisting of
      [^()]*           # any number of characters except parentheses,
      \(               # followed by an opening (
      (?>              # Now match...
       [^()]+          #  one or more characters except parentheses
      |                # or
       \( (?<DEPTH>)   #  a (, increasing the depth counter
      |                # or
       \) (?<-DEPTH>)  #  a ), decreasing the depth counter
      )*               # any number of times
      (?(DEPTH)(?!))   # until the depth counter is zero again,
      \)               # then match the closing )
     )*                # Repeat this any number of times.
     [^()]*            # Then match any number of characters except ()
     \z                # until the end of the string.
    )                  # End of lookahead.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
```

As a single line regex ("The horror! The horror!"), if you insist:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString,@"\sfrom(?=(?:[^()]*\((?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\))*[^()]*\z)"))
```

Comment: ! Please write at bottom, the expression in a single line without comments as i may counter an error while rewriting it.

Comment: What is depth? I had never seen it before. Is it a special word or variable?
\z should be replaced by $ in C#?

Comment: @SamiAkram: It is a variable. `\z` is more specific than `$` (it really only matches at the end of the string, not before any closing whitespace, which is why I prefer it generally), but in this case, you can just as well use `$`.

Comment: string q = "select hi from t1 in (select hello from t2)";


If(Regex.IsMatch(q, @"\sfrom(?(?:[^()]*\((?>[^()]+|\( (?<DEPTH>)|\) (?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\))*[^()]*\z)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))



Got Error:
Parsing Error. Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Comment: @SamiAkram: It looks like you lost quite a few backslashes when copying the regex. Also, the error doesn't make much sense - there is no `{x,y}` quantifier anywhere in this regex.

Comment: There are 6 "\"s i copied all. I also don't know whats {x,y} quantifier however i had faced it whenever i had syntactical inaccuracy in using '*'

Comment: Please make an edit/update to the answer and add a tested straight line of code (which could meet the question requirement which you have already understood) with no explanation and keep above as it is. Please :)

Comment: @Sami: I've just tested it (in Visual C# 2008). It works as is. The condition is met on the string `"foo (bar (baz)) from (spam)"` and is not met on `"foo (bar (baz)) (from (spam))"`.

Comment: And what about "foo (bar (baz)) from (from (spam))" ? It must meet it as well because there exists " from" which is not in any parenthesis. If it meets then if you don't mind please copy paste your pattern string from visual studio  in answer or comment.

Comment: @Sami: Yes, it works too. I've added the comment-free regex, but please use the verbose one. That one's hard enough to read already...

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Its working perfectly. I will prefer the verbose one by making comparison of both. I will use that one because now i have got sure, that's alright. Although I could not get it working, still I was strongly suspecting it the right solution that is why i requested you :) Thanks again....

Comment: Just as a remark, this assumes that you parentheses overall are balanced, it will fail to match "from" outside of a bunch of parentheses if some of them aren't balanced.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want.

```
string s="select field1 dfd t1 (select field1 from t1)select field1 from t1";
Regex r=new Regex(@"(?<=\)|^)\bselect\b.*?\bfrom\b.*?(?=\()",RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
r.Replace(s,"HELL yeah");
```

Comment: Yes Anirudha. You have solved my problem. Thanks for it. I have  used something like that. It is solving my current problem. But not the solution to title as I can have ignoring criteria as 'bb hj exp  ab'
ignore any exp surrounded by 'bb.*exp.*ab'

if I get the solution 'a' ignoring 'a' in 'b'. It will be some combination of any two expressions and dynamically work for new situations. Anyhow you solved my problem, better than i had done, so i am up-voting you. Thanks a lot. Any further help is welcome too.

Comment: This fails with nested parentheses.